# lightning-record-edit-form not showing dependency properly if default value is selected. Is this a bug?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, dependent-picklist

Scenario is :

Object : `ARecord__c` 
Field 1: `Controlling_Field__c`, with values as `CF1, CF2, CF3` 
Field 2: `Dependent_Field__c` with values as `DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4, DF5` 
Record Type : Record 1

Now on dependency level it is set as :

[image]

Now for `Record 1`, values selected for `Controlling_Field__c` and `Dependent_Field__c` are:

Controlling field :

[image]
**NOTE**: CF2 has been made default here.

Dependent Field :
[image]
**NOTE**: DF5 has been made default here.

Now if we create a LWC component to display these via `lightning-record-edit-form`, when the component loads it loads with default values selected above, and it ignores the dependency for the first time. Only once we change the Controlling field from UI it starts showing proper value in Dependent Field.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name='ARecord__c' record-type-id='0127F000000hwtz'>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Controlling_Field__c" required></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Dependent_Field__c" required></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

On load.

[image]

Now change to CF1 and then back to CF2,

The dependent field wont have DF5 anymore as per the Field dependency.

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, why would someone have default on dependent field which is not present in the controlling default? Even if that's an actual use case I wouldn't consider it a bug because it just prioritizes the default value. What do you expect here?

Comment: A lot of use case can be for defaulting a value . If it prioritizes defaulting, then why does it not work when we change the value of controlling field? Expectation is simple , it should respect dependency.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when CF2 is default for Controlling & DF5 for Dependent field & CF2 doesn't have DF5? I either expect Dependent field to have no options or DF5 selected with all options.

Comment: In dependent field it should be selected as 'None' by default as DF5 is not in dependency.

Comment: That makes sense. You may want to play a little with https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/83b87d3772557a22de16f74a047a087a51c4934c/force-app/main/default/lwc/recordEditForm to know whats actually happening.